# Button not enabling on refresh

Tags: javascript, button

User clicks and button gets disabled.

User reloads page.

Button is still disabled.

I want it to be enabled.

I have tried anything from onkeypress f5 to onbeforeunload and nothing works.

Comment: post your script please

Comment: As far as javascript is concerned your page after refresh is completely new so the button is going to go back to its default state. Perhaps you could show some code to give us a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Show us some code.  What does the code look like that disables the button?  What have you tried?

Comment: $(btn).attr('disabled', true); is the whole code for disabling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue I had the misfortune of encountering before, since most browsers rely more and more on local cache to improve page loading. While in chrome usually another page refresh fix it, Firefox is more stubborn.

I solved it by running a function using body onload event. This function detects those incorrectly disabled elements and re-enables them.
To avoid errors there must be a check to indicate weather this page has the elements to check in the first place.

Comment: i did it with $("button:disabled").attr('disabled',false) with $("document").ready()